# Deploy .Net AppEngine

Tags: .net, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, appveyor

I have a .Net AppEngine application working in Google Cloud Platform, and I can deploy it from the command line using my own credentials. I now want to deploy it from my Appveyor CI pipeline. I have encrypted the service account json file and want to use it in my deploy script. Naively I tried the following script in the deploy_script section of appveyor.yml:

```
    dotnet publish -c Release

    gcloud auth activate-service-account xxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --key-file="xxx.json"

    gcloud beta app deploy src/kinetics.webapi/bin/Release/netcoreapp1.1/publish/app.yaml
```

Appveyor has no idea about the Google SDK, as I get the error

> gcloud auth activate-service-account xxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --key-file="xxx.json"
>   'gcloud' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

How do I use gcloud in Appveyor? I suppose I could install the entire Google SDK using Nuget, but that seems a bit time consuming for a CI server. Is there a more lightweight approach?

Answer (score 1):

[Chocolatey Google Cloud SDK installation](https://chocolatey.org/packages/gcloudsdk) takes about 1 minute at AppVeyor VM. You need to add `choco install gcloudsdk` at `install` stage to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Following ilyaf's suggestion, I used Chocolatey to install the Google Cloud SDK. It does work and doing the AppEngine deploy takes so long it's less of a big deal to do this in AppVeyor. Note that there are a couple more steps that are needed to run gcloud: refreshing to pick up the environment variables and using python to run in non-interactive mode. For anyone interested, the following install section installed the tool correctly :

```
install:
  - nuget install secure-file -ExcludeVersion
  - choco install gcloudsdk
  - refreshenv
  - gcloud.cmd components copy-bundled-python>>python_path.txt && SET /p CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=<python_path.txt && DEL python_path.txt
  - gcloud.cmd components update --quiet
  - gcloud.cmd components install beta --quiet
  - secure-file\tools\secure-file -decrypt "xxx.json.enc" -secret %gcp_app_engine_service_account%
deploy_script:
- cmd: >-

    dotnet publish -c Release

    gcloud config set project xxx

    gcloud auth activate-service-account xxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --key-file="xxx.json"

    gcloud beta app deploy src/kinetics.webapi/bin/Release/netcoreapp1.1/publish/app.yaml --quiet
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Needless to say that `gcp_app_engine_service_account` should be a [secure variable](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#secure-variables)